# Dex Save Vs Enemy Attack Roll

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

My party and I were battling a group of orcs and my character turns invisible but doesn't move. The orc I was facing starts randomly swinging his blades in my general direction. I was in range but my DM made me roll a dex save rather than have the orc make an attack roll. Is this the correct call and for future reference how do you know when a dex save or attack roll should be made?

Comment: Did you take the hide action after turning invisible? That makes a difference because as long as you don't take the hide action the Orc still knows where you are, just cannot see you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### If you can’t see your target, your attack rolls have disadvantage

The [rules for unseen targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UnseenAttackersandTargets) say:

> When you attack a target that you can't see, you have disadvantage on the attack roll. This is true whether you're guessing the target's location or you're targeting a creature you can hear but not see. If the target isn't in the location you targeted, you automatically miss, but the DM typically just says that the attack missed, not whether you guessed the target's location correctly.

Nothing here about a dex save. The orc attacking you rolls their attack at disadvantage, still trying to hit your armor class.